# Требуется перевод 'For' для нескольких русскоязычных сайтов в списке сайтов Stack Exchange

Tags: дефект, локализация

Есть список всех сайтов *Stack Exchange* в шапке. В описание к сайтом добавили уточняющее слово "***Для***" (ориг. '***For***'). Нужно бы заменить для сайтов, где описание на русском языке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обратите внимание на японский сайт (справа внизу на картинке).

Comment: Голосовать по багу лучше на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286603/339911).

Comment: @alexolut я заметил. Так понимаю, этого даже в transifex'е нет?

Comment: Угу. Переводу не доступно в текущей реализации.

Comment: @alexolut было такое подозрение...